# Is it possible to change the 'migrations' folder's location outside of the Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-settings

what i'm trying to do is to change the default path for migrations for a specific application in a django project to put it outside the project itself but keeping it transparent, keeping use of *makemigrations* and *migrate*.
Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: First of all, why do you want to put it outside ?

Comment: yes, it MUST be outside for my purpose

Comment: Explain *why*. Migrations are part of each app.

Comment: during Continuous integration the old code will be deleted and the newone will be put in same path and a new migration will be run in case of models' modifies, so i need to keep mi migration files during my versioning

Answer (score 13):

Django has a [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#migration-modules) setting. It allows you to specify a different module for migrations per app. The module can be outside of the Django project, it just needs to be on your python path.

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'myapp': 'othermodule.db_migrations'}
```

Comment: This is pretty handy too for when you want to move the migrations folder into a subfolder of the django app, project>app>database>migrations for example. This way, you can bundle everything that is related to the database: models and migrations.

Comment: How can I specify location for installed independent django app?. I have an installed django app which has all the models and I want to generate migration files and put them under the django project I am using the app into. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @aditya the above answer should work. `myapp` is your installed app, and `othermodule.db_migrations` is in your Django project.