# How to assign the specific path to store the Django Group migration file

Tags: django

There is currently an existing Django system, I want to add some fields to its `Group`, but  other tables were relation `Group` already, so I use add_to_class that's success to add field.
But I have the problem about migration file, the Group's new migration file was stored in `{package path}/djano/contrib/auth/migrations`, But I want to manage those files from our self, Is possibility assign the new path to store those migration files? Because we need these files for deployment.

Comment: It is not clear but did you mean you changed the `Group` model `django.contrib.auth.models`? If so, why?

Comment: But to answer the main question, yes its possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486335/6759844

Comment: Thanks you, its work, and about previous question, Yes, it mean I changed the `Group` model of `django.contrib.auth.models`, the reason is, this system so legacy, and it's already use some  `Group`'s field for major features, so I can't create other model to inheritance `Group`